# didReceiveLocalNotification: UILocalNotification is always nil

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilocalnotification

i have a Problem with Local Notifications:

When i receive a Local Notification and not opening it right away it will stay perfectly in the Notification Center. When i try to open the Notification from the Center it will open the App properly but not calling the didReceiveLocalNotification:... method. When i completely close the App (Taskbar) and tap on the Notification in the Center, it will call the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in which i grab the Notification with

```
[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]
```

the Notification is always nil.

I have this Problem since ios6. Is there any other way to handle that? Or what can cause that problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is this works fine below iOS 6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was a nil Pointer in my UserDefaults, somehow it ran into that nil pointer. There is also something i figured out, when Notifications in the Notification Center are pretty old (by Date) i always got a nil Notification, thats not hold in the memory, i managed that now by my self.